# При попытке открыть главную страницу вылетает ошибка

Tags: ruby-on-rails

При попытке открыть главную страницу вылетает ошибка

```
NoMethodError in Main#index

Showing /home/chernyshovmax/Desktop/app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #5):

2: <html>
3: <head>
4:   <title>App</title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', :media => 'all' %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8: </head>
Rails.root: /home/chernyshovmax/Desktop/app

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___914064924__639802568'
```

В контроллере Main :

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

В вьюхе ничего нет

В роутах:

```
App::Application.routes.draw do
  get "main/index"
  root :to => 'main#index'
end
```

В чем может быть проблемма?

Comment: А стили имеются?

Comment: стили стандартные и еще подключен gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"

Comment: А если на время убрать 5-ю строку из шаблона, то ошибка исчезает?

Comment: Да ошибка пропадает, но тогда стили не подключаются

Comment: Выложи `application.css`

Comment: /*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */

Comment: Стандартный я никаких изменений не вводил

Comment: Ну, теперь удаляй из него по строчке, и выкладывай ту, после удаления которой всё заработает.

Comment: Вот эта строчка
     *= require_tree .

Comment: Значит где-то в папочке 'app/assets/stylesheets', либо в её подпапочках лежит файл, в котором ошибка.

Comment: спасибо буду искать в файлах

Comment: Честно говоря, я не знаю, зачем вообще нужен `twitter-bootstrap-rails`, когда есть официальный [`bootstrap-sass`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass).